# Reverting from Ctrl - Alt - F1

Tags: command-line

I tried to install an nvidia driver and there was an error saying I must not be in an X terminal when doing so. So I did a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

The resulting terminal did not allow the nvidia driver to be installed and showed the same error message. How do I revert back to the Unity GUI?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [What does “Ctrl + Alt + F12” do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/277517/22949)

Comment: Thanks, @EliahKagan! Useful comments are so seldom upvoted on StackExchange. I found that related question very useful when dealing with the problem that brought me to this one, and I'm sure others have/will as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> are the virtual consoles provided by the `getty`/`agetty` programs.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is the console where your X server is running. The GUI (Gnome/KDE or any other) runs over X.
So to get back into your GUI window manager: type:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

or

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

---

[With 17.10 and newer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Desktop), the login screen is on virtual terminal 1, and logged-in users' GUI sessions on VT2 and onwards. So, you may need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> instead.

Comment: Be forewarned -- if you're trying this with a VM while in Windows, this can disable your extended displays -- use `Win` + `P` to recover with Extend

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 works for me.

Answer (score 38):

When you are in a virtual console just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> to move to next/previous virtual console respectively. Console with X is usually seventh.

Comment: What i like about this is that this works accross the distros

Comment: how to close them all then?

Answer (score 25):

For completeness, I'll mention the [`chvt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/chvt.1) command. 
The virtual terminal offers a login prompt, and if you have logged in, you can switch to other VTs:

```
chvt 7
```

will probably get you back to the GUI, since it usually runs on VT7, as mentioned in the other answers.
This is useful for scripting (for example, when taking a screenshot of LightDM).

Answer (score 22):

To revert to the GUI desktop you have to press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Or just `Alt`+`F7`. Holding down `Ctrl` is only necessary when switching *from* the GUI to a text-based virtual console. Switching from one text-based virtual console to another (or to X11) can be accomplished with just `Alt`+`Fn`.

Comment: On `Freebsd` with `Lxde`, I use `Alt`+`F9` to return to Gui from other virtual consoles.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> does not work on LM13 Cinnamon.  However, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> brings it back to GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine on which terminals you and any other users are logged in with the `who` command. For me it was `tty9`, so I had to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

It has been already mentioned that cycling with  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowLeft</kbd> until you get back to your bellowed desktop also works, especially accross distro's (my Fedora 20, for instance, has GUI on <kbd>F2</kbd>), so it's convenient.

There's also a crude method: login and run `sudo service lightdm restart`, which will restart your session ( so yes, you will be logged out and will get back to login screen ). [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/403752/295286) also takes into account that your login manager might not be lightdm, but the idea is the same.