# How to access GUI from TTY mode?

Tags: gui, tty

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit. I am using terminal mode to test a  Window Manager.

I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to terminal mode from the GUI mode. But there is still graphical desktop running in background.

Is there a command to move from CLI to GUI mode so that I can access that GUI?

Comment: use `Ctrl+Alt+F7` to return.

Answer (score 22):

You can either:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> *

Or

Run the command `startx`

---

If your desktop environment is using Wayland

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> instead.

---

* From [the 17.10 Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Desktop):

> - GDM has replaced LightDM as the default display manager. The login screen now uses virtual terminal 1 instead of virtual terminal 7.

Also see [Why is my GDM at a different TTY than my desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/q/910108/158442) for more about the origin of this change.

Comment: I wish this would have been selected as the answer! This has come in handy so many times... it's eerie. Thank you for posting this answer (although it's fairly old).

Comment: I use Lubuntu 20 04 and startx is not found. Ctrl alt F7 brings me to another tty window with Plymouth Boot Screen [ok]

Answer (score 5):

#### To check your default display manager (DM):

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

#### To check if the display manager is running:

```
ps cax | grep display_manager
```

e.g.: if it's `lightdm`:

```
ps cax | grep lightdm
```

(you can then follow up with `echo $?` command, an output `0`(zero) indicate its running or otherwise.)

#### To start a DM:

```
sudo start display_manager
```

e.g.:

```
sudo start lightdm
```

#### To stop a DM:

```
sudo stop display_manager
```

e.g.:

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

#### To restart a DM:

```
sudo restart display_manager
```

e.g.:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Comment: I use Lubuntu 20_04 and there is no start cmd. I have sddm. With service sddm start I have to authenticate as root, entering my password and get a denial.service sddm status shows inactive. What else can I do to start sddm from tty?

Answer (score 4):

Try this command on virtual console,

```
sudo service $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager | awk '{print substr($1,11)}' ) restart
```

Comment: I'd like to know more about this- how does it work? Could you edit your answer to break down the different parts of this line?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann create a chat room and ping me from that. I'll explain..

Answer (score 0):

the best way to test window manager safely is to use [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr/). see man pages for more details.

I assume you use gnome-terminal here.

1. start Xephyr
   $ Xephyr :1
2. Ctrl+Shitf+T open a new tab
   $ export DISPLAY=:1
   $ type_your_window_manager_command_here

Now you can play with your window manager in the Xephyr window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo chvt 1` if you normally do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.