# Black screen with cursor on the top left while upgrading to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

While I am working on my laptop, a popup (notification) came for upgrading my 18.04 system to 20.04.

I accepted it and after an hour the system got logout. I tried a lot to log in, but the same log-in screen is appearing.

So, I did the hardware shut down.

After that, the system is not normal. A black screen is appearing with a blinking mouse on the top.

**How to fix it?**

My trials:

**#1**:

I can go to bios menu via `F12`.

[image]

I tried with the two options ubuntu and its next one, but result is same as title.

**#2**

I can go to terminal type with some random clicking on `Atl+ctrl` plus some F keys. I tried with [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403747/how-to-access-gui-from-tty-mode), but of no use.

[image]

I can update, upgrade etc., and the `lsb_release -a` is showing **20.04**

*Is it possible to fix it from tty?*

Comment: @guiverc how can I see it now? The system is not opening. Afair, the previous version is 18.04.

Comment: @guiverc I didn't remember the mm.

Comment: @guiverc yeah 20.04 possibly... How can I go to normal mode now?

Comment: If you reboot do you get the black screen with the cursor each time? Can you type at that cursor? If so what is the result of typing `ls` ?

Comment: @darth_epoxy can't able to type

Comment: Turn on and continuously press F1 over and over again and see if it takes you to a recovery menu. It's a long shot but give it a go. Otherwise get on another PC and make a bootable USB of this https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/ it has never let me down in the field.