# How can I switch from tty mode, back to Ubuntu studio 23.04 interface?

Tags: boot

I need to let you know, the screen on this HP stream is broken, and an external monitor is in use. I understand that a new laptop is needed, I have to use this one for now.
I am learning a new language, Kotlin, ad used jdkman.io to download the cli. When I rebooted, it will only reboots into Ubuntu 23.04 tty1-6. I have researched everywhere and tried everything to switch back to the normal interface. All I get is a black screen. When I say everything, I mean everything.
What Ithink happened is, right before that, I cleaned up the storage and accidently removed my KDE plasma or something. Because when I do the things I have found to do I get either a error or a black screen.

Another thing to note, I can not connect to my network and there is not Ethernet port. When I go about that with directions I have found, I get an error. So is there anything that can get me back to my normal desktop environment? When I first boot up it does show the Ubuntu studio logo, then it goes to the tty1.

Sorry, let me clear some things up in my question.

1. I am 100% sure I removed KDE Plasma, although when I try and reinstall, there is no network. I do have a bootable flash, since screen is broken, I can't boot from bios using an external monitor, or I am lacking that opportunity on this machine. If I could boot the flash drive(USB) using the command-line, that would do the trick.

When I use ps -ef ! Grep -l tty, I get (standard input).

This may narrow the problem down also. Let's say I just worked with what I have and tried to open a project in Android Studio, like I would in my normal desktop terminal. It says unable to detect graphics environment.

Comment: The Ubuntu Studio log you mention is likely a *plymouth* screen, commonly used to hide system boot messages users can find 'scary'. Ubuntu Studio uses the KDE Plasma desktop, thus if you removed it you'll no longer have a desktop or GUI to use unless you installed another one (ie. Server or text only is what I'd expect). You gave no clear clues as to what you did (*apt logs will allow you to see; did you look?, eg. `view /var/log/apt/history.log` etc*) but you could always `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntustudio-desktop` but I can't give more as you were rather vague.

Comment: Did you already try answers like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/403752/167115)? Also, not sure about SDDM but similar display managers like lightdm use TTY-7 for the GUI. So have you tried TTY-7 and/or TTY-8? If you have an issue using the function key for TTY-7 on your laptop, then you might be able to use `sudo chvt 7` and then check the TTY number with the `tty` command. Also, many commands won't work from the TTY text console becaase there's no DISPLAY variable set, even if a DISPLAY is running somewhere.

Comment: Also also, to get your network running, you should be able to run `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager` or if that is not recognized, then use `sudo systemctl start network-manager` instead.

Comment: The `ps -ef | grep -i tty` command should indicate if a display manager like ssdm or lightdm or whatever is running and if running, should also show which TTY they are running on.

Comment: Also, sometimes this happens after a user downloads their Nvidia driver from the Nvidia website and then later updates their kernel. If this is the case, then you should be able to select to boot up using an older kernel from your GRUB options.