# Ubuntu Search Bar Missing Letter 'e'

Tags: unity-dash

I got a weird problem in Ubuntu 14.04, when I use the dash bar search, if I type in a lower case 'e' it just displays an empty space instead of the actual letter. Capital 'E' works fine, anybody have this kind of issue before?

Comment: is the same problem seen in other cases too

Comment: i mean to say when you type anything in libre office or any offline document

Comment: I got the same problem today !

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by a [corrupted font, ttf-ubuntu-font-family](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1688098&p=10459771#post10459771)

You can use apt-get to reinstall the font by executing the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```

A restart of Unity will be required to re-read the reinstalled font.

You could restart the machine **or** you can attempt restart Unity itself by running

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

I ran this from a Terminal session that was running in my current Unity session and the screen went blank so I had to rerun the `sudo service lightdm restart` command from a Virtual Console I jumped out to the a virtual console using

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd>

I logged in as my self and ran `sudo service lightdm restart`

After Unity restarted I jumped back to Unity by running <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd>

I suspect that the session associated with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd> represents the hanging attempt at the Unity restart but I suppose that will be rectified by a machine restart.

Virtual consoles are handy and are well covered in the following question [Reverting from Ctrl - Alt - F1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157617/reverting-from-ctrl-alt-f1)