# How exit from tty4 terminal without using Alt+SysRq+B to exit?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, tty

How exit from tty4 terminal without using **Alt+SysRq+B**(reset) to exit? Command **Ctrl+Alt+F7** worked for some period, then stopped working, possibly after upgrade system, don't know. Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: Following solutions from [Reverting from Ctrl+Alt+F1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157617/reverting-from-ctrl-alt-f1), try pressing Alt+F7 or Alt+Right

Comment: Works for me. Please report the detailed case on Launchpad Bugtracker.

Comment: `Alt+Right` works for me,  on 3rd pressing.  Alt+F7 - not.

Comment: @minto After 10 minutes googleing, your solution is the only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Well I am currently, working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on virtualbox and I faced the same issue and I resolved it by pressing **Alt + Right** (as mentioned by minto) key sometime. This will take you back to your desktop.