# Teletype tty in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, grub2, gnome, gnome-terminal

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

I used to always use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to log out of my main user, which will show the GUI listing all users you can login to. However, one day I pressed those keys and suddenly a black screen similar to teletype appeared.
The keyboard shortcuts must have reset to default somehow. Even though I don't remember setting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as a special shortcut to log out, which would replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, I imagine the only possible explanation is that I did set that keyboard shortcut to log out, and that it is not the default keyboard shortcut.

I read these two posts:
[Reverting from Ctrl - Alt - F1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157617/reverting-from-ctrl-alt-f1)
[What is a tty, and how do I access a tty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty)

So, I now understand that, in 18.04, the following shortcuts are available:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> exits teletype.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3-6</kbd> takes you to tty3-tty6.

Most AskUbuntu posts I found explain these shortcuts for versions of Ubuntu older than 17.10, so they are not that useful in this case.
My question is, what does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> do on Ubuntu 18.04 ? (What is that black screen with 15-20 lines of white text that do not let you type in any input? )

And, what does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> do on  Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: 'teletype' is a terminal window.

Comment: @K7AAY , Wikipedia says: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter . What the screen shows when I press Ctrl+Alt+F3 is different from when I just launch the Terminal app on Ubuntu. So, I think 'teletype' is indeed a terminal window, but it has to be some sort of special 'terminal window', because I am not familiar with it. The second post I linked in my post explains some of the differences.

Comment: Do you have any clue of what is that screen that shows when I press CtrlAltF1 ? It's different from tty3-tty6, and it does not show 'tty' at the top. So, if it's not tty, what is it? And why is it that it doesn't let me type in anything?

Comment: Aha! Already answered in another post. See https://askubuntu.com/a/979029/197910