# Mysterious behaviour of sudo apt-get install when installing wine64

Tags: apt, wine

So i was helping a friend of mine install wine so that she could play roblox, and something happened
I remote controled her screen. I did sudo apt-get install wine-stable. It said it needed wine64 and when i tried installing it, it said it needed winelib, so i installed it and then tried instaallin wine64. When i did that, the command prompt started uninstalling things. Most her apps were gone. She restarted her computer and ubuntu started in some sort of command prompt mode. I told her to do alt f7 but it did not work. Her computer hen went black. What do i do. Feel free to ask details
Note:she had her OS gui on when that happened

Comment: You may be aware of the fact that on Ubuntu-17.10 and newer, GUI not comes on Ctrl+Alt+F1, or Ctrl+Alt+F2, https://askubuntu.com/a/157621/1107236

Comment: Possibly she need to set up network (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic), and install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: @turbulence she had her gui on, but linux started that time on command line mode. Added it to the question

Comment: If the network connectivity is there, you can try to install the package ubuntu-desktop. It should install the basic applications.

Comment: Apparently the computer is 32bit so installing a 64bit package conflicted with existing packages.

Comment: Yeah, GUI on newer versions using GDM is on CTRL+ALT+F1 or CTRL+ALT+F2 but if you are using `ligtdm` it should still be on CTRL+ALT+F7

Comment: Also, did the system have nvidia drivers that were manually installed?

Answer (score 0):

Your `/var/log/apt/history.log` contains a list of all installed and uninstalled packages. You can use a few commands to make it easier to reinstall the packages without having to type out each package.

**First**, identify the packages. The following commands will list all the packages that were removed and will also create a file containing the list:

```
cd
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -A3 "install wine64" | grep "Remove" | tee install-list
```

**Now**, we need to clean up the list so run the following command to remove the word "Remove," all the stuff within parentheses, and commas:

```
sed -e 's/Remove://g;s/([^)]*)//g;s/,//g' install-list
```

The list should consist of package names that may or may not include the architecture in a format similar to `example-packagename:i386 anotherpackage-1-2.3:i386 awesome-packagename:i386` or maybe like this `example-packagename:amd64 anotherpackage-1-2.3:amd64 awesome-packagename:amd64`

**If this list of uninstalled packages looks correct**, run the following command to apply the changes (use the up arrow key to get to the last command and simply change `sed -e` to `sed -i` so you don't have to type it all over again:

```
sed -i 's/Remove://g;s/([^)]*)//g;s/,//g' install-list
```

**Now to install the packages**, run the following command but this time review the output before you accept the changes (it should list some packages to uninstall like amd64 packages and all the wine stuff):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install $(cat ./install-list)
```

Please post any errors.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why this happened in the first place but if you try installing `wine64` again, do not use `sudo apt install -y` and use `apt install wine64` instead so you can review the changes before you accept. Then, you can go through the list and determine the problem or ask a question about it here to help figure out a solution for installation.